# Use attribute selector for selecting by class instead of proper class selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm just working on a email html template and I came across this:

`*[class=width100pc] { width: 100% !important; }`

I've never seen something like this before. Is there a reason of using this syntax for selecting by class instead of just using

`.width100pc {width: 100% !important;}`

I know that CSS is kind of limited in email clients, is it somehow related to it?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `*[class=width100pc]` to style any element where `width100pc` is the **only class**.

```css
*[class=width100pc] { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="width100pc">Hello</div>

<div class="width100pc another-class">world!</div>
```

A standard class selector will apply regardless of other classes.

```css
.width100pc { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="width100pc">Hello</div>

<div class="width100pc another-class">world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The one reason that comes to my mind is when class selector is not supported in a specific environment where this code is used, but can be bypassed by using attribute selector.

Comment: Maybe email clients are one of those environments (?)